# Is there a better way? Long ELSIF state machine alternatives

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, counter, state-machine

I was wondering if somebody could give me some advice. I am trying to design a module that takes 8 inputs (buttons).
These buttons determine if the state is active or not. Then on the rising edge of the clock it sequentially moves forwards or backwards through the active states,
skipping the inactive clock states.

for example:

If the inputs are 11111111. It counts 00000001, 00000010, 00000100, 00001000, 00010000, 00100000, 01000000, 10000000. continuously

If the inputs are 00001111. It counts 00000001, 00000010, 00000100, 00001000. continuously.

If the inputs are 00000011. It counts 00000001, 00000010. continuously.

I am new to VHDL and fpga. I have tried a few different approaches. All of them have had
problems. But this state machine i have written is working the way i want.
It basically starts at state 0, checks which direction its moving then checks for the next active state in that directon and moves to it.

for example:

if in state 0 and moving forwards it checks input 2, if backwards it checks input 8. If they are not active it checks input 3 and input 7.
if they are active it moves to that state and goes through the process again. But this time because we are in a different state it starts the check from this new state. If we are in state 2. It checks input 3 if forward and input 1 if backwards. If active it moves to that state.

Its a bit long with a lot of repeating code and is very much like C code. I would like to get away from this if I can. But as I said my knowledge is limited and I would like to know if there is a better way to achieving the function I need. Any help and guidance would be appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Here is the code for the module.

```
library ieee;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY state_machine IS
PORT(
  clk      : IN   STD_LOGIC;
  a        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state0 Active '1'
  b        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state1 Active '1'
  c        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state2 Active '1'
  d        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state3 Active '1'
  e        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state4 Active '1'
  f        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state5 Active '1'
  g        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state6 Active '1'
  h        : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- state7 Active '1'
  dir      : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- direction
  reset    : IN   STD_LOGIC;
  output   : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0));  
END state_machine;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF state_machine IS
   TYPE STATE_TYPE IS (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7);
   SIGNAL state : STATE_TYPE;     
BEGIN
  sequence: PROCESS (clk, reset)
  BEGIN
  IF reset = '1' THEN
     state <= s0;
  ELSIF (rising_edge (clk)) THEN     
    
  CASE state IS       
       WHEN s0=>                          -- When in state 0
       IF (dir = '1') THEN                -- if direction is forwards
           IF b = '1' THEN  state <= s1;  -- If b is 1 go to state 1...if not
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;  -- if c is 1 go to state 2...if not
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;  -- if d is 1 go to state 3...if not
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;  -- if e is 1 go to state 4...if not
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;  -- if f is 1 go to state 5...if not
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;  -- if g is 1 go to state 6...if not
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;  -- if h is 1 go to state 7...if not
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;  -- if a is 1 go to state 0   
        END IF;                
       ELSE                               -- if direction is backwards
           IF h = '1' THEN  state <= s7;  -- If h is 1 go to state 1...if not
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;  -- if g is 1 go to state 2...if not
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;  -- if f is 1 go to state 3...if not
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;  -- if e is 1 go to state 4...if not
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;  -- if d is 1 go to state 5...if not
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;  -- if c is 1 go to state 6...if not
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;  -- if b is 1 go to state 7...if not
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;  -- if a is 1 go to state 0...if not                                                        
        END IF;                         
       END IF;
           
       WHEN s1=>                          
       IF (dir = '1') THEN 
           IF c = '1' THEN  state <= s2;         
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3; 
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' THEN  state <= s1; 
        END IF;             
       ELSE                  
           IF a = '1' THEN  state <= s0;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7; 
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;                                
        END IF;        
       END IF;
           
       WHEN s2=>
       IF (dir = '1') THEN 
           IF d = '1' THEN  state <= s3;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        END IF; 
       ELSE  
           IF b = '1' THEN  state <= s1;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0; 
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        END IF;   
       END IF;
           
       WHEN s3=>
       IF (dir = '1') THEN 
           IF e = '1' THEN  state <= s4;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5; 
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        END IF; 
       ELSE
           IF c = '1' THEN  state <= s2;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1; 
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        END IF;     
      END IF;
           
       WHEN s4=>
       IF (dir = '1') THEN
           IF f = '1' THEN  state <= s5;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6; 
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        END IF; 
       ELSE
           IF d = '1' THEN  state <= s3;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2; 
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;           
        END IF;
      END IF;
           
       WHEN s5=>
       IF (dir = '1') THEN
           IF g = '1' THEN  state <= s6;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7; 
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s5;
        END IF; 
       ELSE
           IF e = '1' THEN  state <= s4;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3; 
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;     
        END IF;
       END IF;
           
        WHEN s6=>
       IF (dir = '1') THEN         
           IF h = '1' THEN  state <= s7;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        END IF; 
       ELSE
           IF f = '1' THEN  state <= s5;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4; 
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        END IF;
       END IF;
           
        WHEN s7=>
       IF (dir = '1') THEN           
           IF a = '1' THEN  state <= s0;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5;
        elsif g = '1' then  state <= s6;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        END IF; 
       ELSE
           IF g = '1' THEN  state <= s6;         
        elsif f = '1' then  state <= s5; 
        elsif e = '1' then  state <= s4;
        elsif d = '1' then  state <= s3;
        elsif c = '1' then  state <= s2;
        elsif b = '1' then  state <= s1;
        elsif a = '1' then  state <= s0;
        elsif h = '1' then  state <= s7;
        END IF;
       END IF;
           
     END CASE;
  END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS (state)
BEGIN
  CASE state IS
     WHEN s0 =>
        output <= "000";
     WHEN s1 =>
        output <= "001";
     WHEN s2 =>
        output <= "010";
     WHEN s3 =>
        output <= "011";
     WHEN s4 =>
        output <= "100";
     WHEN s5 =>
        output <= "101";
     WHEN s6 =>
        output <= "110";
     WHEN s7 =>
        output <= "111";
  END CASE;
END PROCESS;

END behaviour;
```

here is the testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity state_machine_tb is
end;

architecture bench of state_machine_tb is

component state_machine
 PORT(
    clk      : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    a        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    b        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    c        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    d        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    e        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    f        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    g        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    h        : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    dir      : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    reset    : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    output : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0));
end component;

signal clk      : STD_LOGIC;
signal a        : STD_LOGIC;
signal b        : STD_LOGIC;
signal c        : STD_LOGIC;
signal d        : STD_LOGIC;
signal e        : STD_LOGIC;
signal f        : STD_LOGIC;
signal g        : STD_LOGIC;
signal h        : STD_LOGIC;
signal dir      : STD_LOGIC;
signal reset    : STD_LOGIC;
signal output :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);

constant clock_period: time := 10 ns;

begin

uut: state_machine port map ( clk    => clk,
                            a      => a,  
                            b      => b,
                            c      => c,
                            d      => d,  
                            e      => e,
                            f      => f,
                            g      => g,
                            h      => h,
                            dir    => dir,
                            reset  => reset,
                            output => output);

stimulus: process
begin
reset <= '1';
dir <= '1'; 
a <= '1';
b <= '1';
c <= '1';
d <= '1';
e <= '1';
f <= '1';
g <= '1';
h <= '1';
wait for clock_period;
reset <= '0';  
wait for clock_period *15;
dir <= '0';
a <= '1';
b <= '1';
c <= '1';
d <= '1';
e <= '1';
f <= '1';
g <= '1';
h <= '1';
wait for clock_period *16;
dir <= '1';
a <= '1';
b <= '1';
c <= '1';
d <= '1';
e <= '0';
f <= '0';
g <= '0';
h <= '0';
wait for clock_period *16;
dir <= '0';
a <= '1';
b <= '1';
c <= '1';
d <= '1';
e <= '0';
f <= '0';
g <= '0';
h <= '0';
wait for clock_period *16;
dir <= '1';
a <= '1';
b <= '0';
c <= '1';
d <= '0';
e <= '1';
f <= '0';
g <= '1';
h <= '0';
wait for clock_period *16;
a <= '1';
b <= '1';
c <= '0';
d <= '0';
e <= '0';
f <= '0';
g <= '0';
h <= '0';
wait for clock_period *16;
a <= '1';
b <= '0';
c <= '0';
d <= '0';
e <= '0';
f <= '0';
g <= '0';
h <= '0';
wait for clock_period *4;
dir <= '0';  
wait;
end process;

clocking: process
begin
  clk <= '0';
  wait for clock_period / 2;
  clk <= '1';
  wait for clock_period / 2;
end process;

end;
```

Comment: Start by refining the specification. We know what "00001111" does, but how about "00001000"? Or "00001110"? Then look for some regularity you can use to simplify the problem description. And as Renaud suggests, you have a type system; use it and counting etc will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

What about using more convenient types, like a vector for your input buttons and an integer for your state? Something like the following (not tested):

```vhdl
entity state_machine is
  port(
    clk:  in std_ulogic;
    rst:  in std_ulogic;
    btn:  in std_ulogic_vector(0 to 7);
    dir:  in std_ulogic;
    cnt: out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0)
  );
end entity state_machine;

architecture rtl of state_machine is
  signal state: natural range 0 to 7;
begin
  cnt <= std_ulogic_vector(to_unsigned(state, 3));

  process(clk, rst)
    variable v: natural range 0 to 7;
  begin
    if rst = '1' then
      state <= 0;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      for i in 1 to 7 loop
        if dir = '1' then
          v := (state + i) mod 8;
        else
          v := (state - i) mod 8;
        end if;
        if btn(v) = '1' then
          exit;
        end if;
--      exit when btn(v) = '1'; -- VHDL2008 version of above if
      end loop;
      state <= v;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture rtl;
```

If what you need is a Mealy state machine, instead of a Moore state machine (what the above describes), you can slightly modify the code to make the next state explicit and compute your outputs from the next state instead of the current state (not tested):

```vhdl
entity state_machine is
  port(
    clk:  in std_ulogic;
    rst:  in std_ulogic;
    btn:  in std_ulogic_vector(0 to 7);
    dir:  in std_ulogic;
    cnt: out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0)
  );
end entity state_machine;

architecture rtl of state_machine is
  signal state, next_state: natural range 0 to 7;
begin
  cnt <= std_ulogic_vector(to_unsigned(next_state, 3));

  process(state, dir, btn)
    variable v: natural range 0 to 7;
  begin
    for i in 1 to 7 loop
      if dir = '1' then
        v := (state + i) mod 8;
      else
        v := (state - i) mod 8;
      end if;
      if btn(v) = '1' then
        exit;
      end if;
--    exit when btn(v) = '1'; -- VHDL2008 version of above if
    end loop;
    next_state <= v;
  end process;

  process(clk, rst)
  begin
    if rst = '1' then
      state <= 0;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      state <= next_state;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am getting a syntax error in this section:                                       
break when btn(v) = '1';

Comment: It's a VHDL2008 feature. What version of the standard are you using? I edited my code to show a variant that should work with older VHDL versions.

Comment: I changed the word break to exit. All works fine now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ooops, my bad, I mixed-up between several languages. I should have tested first. Sorry.

Comment: Hello again. Is there a way to update the cnt output immediatly. At the moment it updates one cycle after. I have changed a few things but all i have been able to do is extend the update to 2 clock cycles. thanks.

Comment: @DionnakiCore Well, what you specified in your question is a Moore state machine: you have a synchronous process (with a clock) that updates the state register on rising edges of the clock. And a combinational process that updates your outputs depending on the current state. So, yes, you need to wait for the next rising edge of the clock to see your outputs updated. This is how Moore state machines work. If you prefer a Mealy state machine it's a different specification. I edit my answer to show how to code it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Renaud.